# Double slash when 301ing from foo.com to www.foo.com with Django / Apache / mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, virtualhost, http-status-code-301

We have a Django application running on Apache through mod_wsgi.

Our main domain is foo.com (without www), but we want to manage also www requests redirecting them to the main with a 301.

I've setup the thing in this way

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80>

   DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/foo.com/public
   ServerName foo.com
   ServerAlias www.foo.com

   Alias /media/  /var/www/vhosts/foo.com/public/media/
   Alias /static/ /var/www/vhosts/foo.com/public/static/

   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    !=foo.com [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$          http://foo.com/$1 [L,R=301]


   <Directory /var/www/vhosts/foo.com/public>
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
       AllowOverride All
   </Directory>

   WSGIDaemonProcess foo.com processes=5 threads=30 display-name=%{GROUP}
   WSGIProcessGroup foo.com

   WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/vhosts/foo.com/fooproject/fooproject/wsgi.py

   LogLevel debug
   ErrorLog /var/www/vhosts/foo.com/logs/error.log
   CustomLog /var/www/vhosts/foo.com/logs/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Everything works, but i got double slashes for every request at www.foo.com

Examples:

```
www.foo.com -> foo.com//
www.foo.com/ -> foo.com//
www.foo.com/page  -> foo.com//page
```

Normally that rule works for PHP sites.

What can be? Is there something i can look at to understand it?

PS. I've set Django `APPEND_SLASH` to `False`

Comment: could this be the culprit? `http://foo.com/$1` It looks fine to me though.

Comment: ok i didn't tried it before. this fix the calls with a page but not the homepage. i'm updating the question now

Comment: See if this does anything (pulled from Apache docs): `RewriteRule   ^/(.+)  http://foo.com/$1  [L,R=301]`

Comment: found it. i got trapped from the proxy resolution cache or something similar. @karthikr if you want to answer with your suggestion (RewriteRule ^(.*)$          http://foo.com$1 [L,R=301])  i'll be pleased to flag your answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$          http://foo.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

To

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$          http://foo.com$1 [L,R=301]
```